# How to create an interactive heatmap with Python?

Tags: python, data-visualization, heatmap, interactive, python-interactive

I'm trying to create an interactive Heatmap in Jupyter :

I want to be able to display a graph when double-clicking on the different cells. For instance when clicking on the cell corresponding to correlation between A and B I want to display a graph showing corr(A,B) across time.
It appears that neither plotly nor seaborn allows me to do that. Any help is well appreciated !

Comment: using [Plotly](https://plotly.com/python/heatmaps/) library for interactive plots ;)

Comment: Unfortunately plotly doesn't allow me to do that :/

Comment: If you can, share your data with us to make a plot for you with Plotly.